# Are all Kryptonian objects "super" under a yellow sun?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Superman's original cape made from his swaddling blanket is indestructible.

Are other Kryptonian artifacts, materials, substances or products of similar super durability? Or, are only certain materials?

For instance, was his cape/blanket made from an organic material that could thus have "supercharged cells"? Or was it Kryptonian engineering that makes his cape, and original space shuttle (as @Richard pointed out) "super".

Strictly comic canon, but examples from any Age are fair game. Examples could be of other super items, or counter-examples of things from Krypton that are not indestructible/super.

(Please exclude Kryptonite, in its various forms, from consideration.)

Comment: His entire pod is "super", the crystalline glass has hypnotic powers and can't be melted, the rubber lining is inflammable and was used to make his boots, the metal can't be melted (Superman uses it to shave by bouncing his eye-beams off it).

Comment: @Richard Are those properties from the yellow sun, or by virtue of advanced Kryptonian engineering?

Comment: Good question. Dunno. Krypton is supposedly hyper-dense, maybe it's something to do with that.

Comment: @sumelic - Yes, non-flammable. Oops

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean like I bring an apple from Krypton and the yellow sun charges the apples cells to make them bulletproof? The super level of the rocket ship was always attributed to advanced Kryptonian technology as I understand it, nothing to do with the yellow sun.

Comment: @Broklynite An apple, a sword, a different kind of fabric, anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being unclear apparently. An apple would undergo super-ification as a biological product undergoing influence of a yellow sun. But you're asking about influence of the yellow sun on non-biological materials as well then? Well, anything using silver nitrate is likely going to be a little different, heh.

Comment: The furthest extension of this question: would Krypton not have been destroyed had they moved it into orbit around Earth's sun?

Comment: @Xantec That may be, but what I'm trying to suss out is if it's only purely organic objects that react in such a way, or only certain ones, or even things *made* from them (wooden?), or are certain alien substances/compounds included? I doubt the whole planet would be, and so I wanted to limit it to objects. I know that Supes has found some artifacts here and there, but...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.** It's explictly stated in [Superman #146](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_146) ("*The Complete Story of Superman's Life!*"), that all objects from Krypton are 'Super' when they come to Earth. This includes Superman's swaddling cloths and pod as well as Supergirl's pod and all the contents within.

[image]

[Action Comics #252](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_252) also contains the following panel. Kara Zor-El's mother seems pretty confident that her normal material will becomes "super" under a yellow sun.

[image]

Comment: Wow, finally! Perfect. Is the link how you came across this?

Comment: @CreationEdge - I spotted this panel when I was perusing images for my "[How did the Kents raise a Super-baby](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120680/20774)" answer

Comment: The caption on that first Superman #146 panel seems to be immediately contradicted by the fact that the nose cone of the spacecraft has clearly crumpled on impact.

Comment: @Buzz - It's designed to do that for insurance purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Note: All quotes here come NOT from DC stories, but from the [*Smallville* Wikia](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Yellow_sun), so take of this what you will.

To (attempt) answer your question, lets see how the yellow sun affects the things it "hits".

> The yellow sun is a yellow star of average size, and sustains all life on Earth with its heat, providing nourishment to the organisms there.

This will indeed nourish all living things, but what about non-sentient beings:

> The force field shields Clark's body and the surrounding area from external forces; as a result, his clothes can sometimes survive the impact of an explosion.

This most certainly has an affect to make his clothes more durable and strong when he needs them, but this doesn't answer your whole question.

I couldn't find any place where it was described as giving all non-sentient things "super" abilities, though I can guess it does as long as it has an effect or is with something that has "super" abilities.

I also imagine if someone put a spirit in an item (don't know if this is possible) they would get powers as stated here:

> Kryptonian spirits, while inhabiting a human host that lives under a yellow sun, can gain powers.

That's the best I got!

Comment: Please add citations to your quotes.

Comment: They all come from the same source, though I'll add in which they came from soon.

Comment: same source, add links?

Answer (score 2):

[Elliot S! Maggin describes the photonucleic effect in fair detail](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Photonucleic_Effect).  The short of it seems to be that,

> "Inorganic matter that originally formed in the orbit of a red giant like the star of Krypton almost never makes its way around interstellar space into the system of a yellow star. It is simply unlikely in the extreme. When, rarely, it does happen, it tends to develop an unstable and unpredictable radioactivity at the molecular level"
>
> ...Where non-living matter becomes unstable and radioactive with this dislocation, living things develop an enhanced stability.

I'll admit I'm no expert on the DC universe, but from the research I've done, the explanation seems to be that organic matter is enhanced, inorganic matter becomes destabilized and as we know in some cases, deadly.  The exceptions to this seem to be technological.  I would argue that the pod featured super abilities based on superior engineering and materials.  Another example are the Sunstone crystals used to build structures and even what we might think of as computers.  That one is debatable though, as [Sunstones themselves may actually be organic.](http://dcuniverseonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sunstone_Crystal)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

I've had some time to find copies of the citations made before.

In **Superman: Birthright** Jonathan Kent grew frustrated with the emotional distance with his now-adult son Clark...

[image]

so he sought to take out his frustrations. He did this by getting a sledgehammer and taking it to the shed, and proceeding to *wail out like batting practice on Clark's ship!*

[image]

[image]

The ship was undamaged in the slightest, but the vibrations it amplified caused the barn to collapse; Clark had to fly in and save his dad, telling him "it's like *me* ; you *can't* damage it." I was actually mistaken on this: Clark alluded to the ship and him having similar structure fortified by the sun in an *earlier* issue, seen here:

[image]

Similar again to the spaceship in **Smallville** ; the only thing that finally destroyed it, was a key made of Kryptonite, seen here:

Answer (score 0):

in the New 52, although Kryptonian materials were naturally durable even on their *own* planet, them being fortified to nearly *indestructible* levels via their molecular density and Earth's sun seems to be the case as well. Such was stated to Supergirl's suit:

[image]